# Perform a calculation and change tab [Shiny app]

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I need to perform a calculation (parameters to define it are in the sidebar) and, once done, move to the plot to see final results (`tab2`) and not see `tab1`. So, I'd like that "Predict" (action) button follows the order and moves to second tab.

[image]

I tried something like that, but Shiny's world is very new for me:

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
      fluidPage(
            sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                             uiOutput('manySliders'),
                             actionButton('add', 'Predict'),
                             br(), br(),
                             helpText('Press Quit to exit the application'),
                             actionButton('quit', 'Quit')),
            mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id = 'tabs',
                  tabPanel('tab1', uiOutput('markdown')),
                  tabPanel('tab2', plotOutput('plot'))
            )
      )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){
...
    new.d <- reactive({
        input$add
        isolate(observeEvent(input$add, {updateTabsetPanel(session, "tab1", selected = 'tab2')})) 
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please never nest `observeEvent` in `reactive`. You can use `bindEvent` or `eventReactive`. Furthermore `updateTabsetPanel` needs the `inputId` of the element to update (not the currently active tabname):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput('manySliders'),
      actionButton('add', 'Predict'),
      br(), br(),
      helpText('Press Quit to exit the application'),
      actionButton('quit', 'Quit')),
      mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id = 'tabs',
                            tabPanel('tab1', uiOutput('markdown')),
                            tabPanel('tab2', plotOutput('plot'))
      )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "tabs", selected = 'tab2')
  })
  
  result <- eventReactive(input$add, {
    return(1:10)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(result())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Nice! Indeed, I was also understanding `inputId` as the "mother" tab... Thanks for your help!